Family of all partial sequences
Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with no repeated elements. Define $\xi$ as the family of all partial sequences of $(a_n)$. We need to prove the cardinality of $\xi$:
Objective: Prove that $|\xi| = 2^{\aleph_0}$.
**
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/3Kak7eil.jpg

Sorry, this MO website is for questions of math research.
